# Trying to build System.Runtime.Caching from Microsoft/referencesource

Tags: c#, .net, caching, roslyn

I'm trying to build on my machine the System.Runtime.Caching project in Visual Studio 2015. The build fails because there is no definition for the classes:

```
private CacheExpires _expires;
private CacheUsage _usage;
```

CacheExpires and CacheUsage are not defined in this project and also not in any other project from the .net framework, and even in the Reference Source [website](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Caching) there is no definition for those classes.

Those classes are used in MemoryCacheEntry.cs and MemoryCacheStore.cs

Has anyone succeed to build it? Am I doing something wrong or is this project not completely open source?

thanks!

Comment: The dirty approach is to use a disassembler, but this is probably a violation of the license.  If you are interested in being able to build the .Net framework, I would encourage you to play with mono instead; most scenarios where you would need to build the reference source are probably violations of the reference source license.  See also [Mono's implementation of `CacheUsage.cs`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Runtime.Caching/ReferenceSources/CacheUsage.cs).  "This file implements the classes UsageEntryRef and CacheUsage missing from .NET reference source"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot build from Reference Source; it doesn't include build steps, generated code, localisation, and other things.

That's why it's called *Reference* Source.

Comment: source code is source code;) Even if you want to call it reference. Indeed, it is nearly possible to build it, only two class definitions are missing.

Comment: @Rafa: It may be nearly possible to build that part, but most of the reference source is _very_ unbuildable (especially because of localisation)

Comment: @SLaks: To be fair to Rafa, the Caching project does include a `csproj` file.  It's not completely crazy to try to build it.